# uploadify in asp

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

is it possible to use uploadify in asp (not .Net)?

Comment: You should probably add a little more detail (like what code you've already tried, etc). Otherwise, some smart-ass like me is going to post a simple 'Yes' as the answer (and they'd be right).

Comment: Hey...this smart-ass is trying to back up his 'yes' answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing what you're trying to do, my initial answer is yes.  I don't see why not.

You're rending HTML down to the client regardless -- just have your `<script>` tags set properly and you're ready to rock n' roll!  ASP outputs HTML to the client, which is just what ASP.NET, PHP and a number of other web technologies output.  ASP is just the mechanism you're using to provide some sort of dynamic content to your pages.

Also, it's important to note that the requirements for uploadify do not specify the server-side technology to use:

> Requirements
>
> - jQuery v1.2.x or greater
> - SWFObject v2.2 or greater
> - Flash Player v9.0.24 or greater

It's all client-side technology requirements.

If you provide more details, we can probably give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this having a look at this and see if it helps: [Implement Uploadify jQuery Plugin in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Uploadify-jQuery-Plugin-in-ASPNet.aspx)